# Is there a way to show an "expression" correctly in a "paste"?

Tags: r, label, expression, paste

I have an expression like this in R:

```
ylabel <- expression("NO"[3]*"-N-Concentration [mg/l]")
```

This should be the label of my y-axis on my ggboxplot.
Because the y-label is too close to the axis, I use `\n` (new line) to create more distance to the axis:

```
ylab=paste(ylabel,"\n")
```

But then on my plot my label will not be shown correctly as I expected:

[Wrong formated label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KDlQ.png)

Does anybody know how to resolve this problem?
I have searched the forum but I am unfortunately still not successful.

**Edit:**
I just added a small example to reproduce the problem:

```
ylabel <- expression("NO"[3]*"-N-Concentration [mg/l]")
par(mar=c(6,8,1,1))
y=c(1,1,2,2,3,4,5)
plot(y, ylab=paste(ylabel,"\n"))
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example.  The `y_name` is giving errors

Comment: Try with `bquote` i.e. `plot(1:10, main = bquote('NO'[3]*-N-Concentration [mg/l]~"\n"))`

Comment: `the y-label is too close to the axis, I use \n (new line) to create more distance` this question and answers below is a perfect example of an xy problem. just use `title(ylab = ylabel, line = 4)` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `bquote` which does evaluate the expression with `atop`

```
par(mar =  c(3, 6,  2, 2))
 plot(1:10, ylab = bquote(atop(NO[3]*-N-Concentration [mg/l], "\n")))
```

-output

[image]

---

Or if we need the expression

```
par(mar =  c(3, 6,  2, 2))
ylabel <- expression(atop(NO[3]*-N-Concentration [mg/l], "\n"))
plot(y, ylab=ylabel)
```

-output

[image]

---

Or as the OP mentioned in comments if the `[mg/l]` needs to be showed as is, then just quote it

```
ylabel <- expression(atop(NO[3]*-N-Concentration*" [mg/l]", "\n"))
par(mar =  c(3, 6,  2, 2))
plot(1:10, ylab = ylabel)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! But if I put the \n inside the expression, it does not add more space between the label and the axis as it does when I use the option ylab=paste(ylabel,"\n").

And bquote doesn't solve my problem unfortunately.

Comment: @PDUY In the second graph, the label and axis space is almost to the limit

Comment: @PDUY But with the `paste`, I can't even see the title anymore unless change the margins

Comment: @PDUY Do you want the `NO3-N` in first line and Concentration-mg/l in next line.  The one you asked is kind of going out of the margins

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and help!
I want all the text in one line, just want to put more space to the axis.

I have done many previous plots with the same code so all are having the same distance to axis (they don't need an expression to be expressed).
But now with this NO3 it comes to problem.

And yes, I haved changed my margins too :(

It seems to me that there is no way to use an expression inside a paste. So I will follow your second suggestion and edit the plot manually afterwards.

Comment: @PDUY try with the update on `expression` in my post

Comment: @PDUY can you check the updates.  I am guessing that this should work now

Comment: Oh thanks. It worked! But I wonder how can I put the [mg/l] in normal, not in subscript?
Oh I figured it out, Thanks very much!!!

Comment: @PDUY you had the mg/l wihtin the square brackets which I thought you wanted as subscripts

Comment: Using this should work, thank you again: `ylabel <- expression(atop(NO[3]*-N-Concentration*" [mg/l]", "\n"))`

Answer (score 1):

We could use `substitute`:

```
plot(y, 
     ylab=substitute(paste("NO"[3]*-N-Concentration [mg/l],"\n"), list(ylabel[2])))
```

[image]